# Read configuration file in Django views.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

My question is simple: **how to read any .txt or .ini file from views.py in Django project?**

I need to get a simple parameter (ex. 4) from settings. I dropped my `setting.ini` in one dir with `views.py` (in app folder). And nothing from the previous answers seem to work:

In views.py:
`filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'setting.ini')`

returns FileNotFoundError, stating the exact right location, but being unable to read it: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\XXXX\\XX\\XXXX\\XXXX\\setting.ini'

Setting PROJECT_ROOT in `settings.py` also doesn't help. When I drop `setting.ini` in one folder with `settings.py` and try
`import os`
`from django.conf.settings import PROJECT_ROOT`
`file_ = open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'filename'))`

FileNotFoundError as well.

Current app folder contents:
`migrations/`
`static/`
`templates/`
`__init__`
`admin.py`
`models.py`
`setting.ini`
`tests.py`
`views.py`

Comment: your settings file is in same directory as views.py so why are you using path.join. Just open the file with its filename it would work'

Comment: I use: `with open('setting.ini', 'r') as f:` still FileNotFoundError. Even though setting.ini and views.py are in the same folder

Comment: Try to build absolute path to access the file and check the path that you built is correct.

Comment: The path is absolutely correct even when the error is showing: No such file or directory

Comment: how about `yourapp/setting.ini` or `.setting.ini`, does it work?

Comment: The problem is solved: It was my Windows system settings - hiding `txt` from `setting.ini.txt`

Answer (score 1):

In `views.py` where you have the `setting.ini` file in the same directory.

```
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'setting.ini')
print('My settings', open(filename).readlines())
```

Comment: still FileNotFoundError

Comment: Double check the file names and locations then. Maybe `settings.ini`?

Comment: It's `setting.ini`. I added the complete folder contents in my question.